# VLCJ - Blank screen when transparent background

Tags: java, swing, vlcj

I am using `vlcj` to show videos with an `OutOfProcessMediaPlayerComponent` in an application. To do so I add the video canvas to thwe content pane of a undecorated `JDialog`. That works fine as expected but when i set the background color of the dialog to transparent, the video canvas staqys blank and video does not work anymore. The behaviour is reproducible and is done with the following code:

```
[...]
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JDialog videoPopup = new JDialog(owner);
videoPopup.setUndecorated(true);
videoPopup.setType(Window.Type.NORMAL);
videoPopup.setModalityType( Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
videoPopup.setContentPane(contentPane);
contentPane.setOpaque(false);
contentPane.add(videoCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
videoPopup.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0)); // This line destroys the video playback function
```

I want to create popup with transparent background containing my videopanel and other stuff, why does videoplayback break when setting the background to transparent?

Answer (score 0):

In one of my software to get a transparent window, I use

```
float opacity = 0.5f; // between 0.0f and 1.0f
myFrame.setOpacity(opacity);
```

Note that the background on my frame (content pane) is Color.BLACK
Maybe that will work also for your dialog.

Comment: Does `setOpacity` really make the window transparent and not its contained components like e.g. a button? I need to keep the components full opaque. Im not quite sure reading the docs... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setOpacity(float)

Comment: In my case (a JLabel with an image), it also made the content (semi) transparent.